# Field Widget Ajax

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

I'm trying to add an ajax callback in a FieldWidget.
I definied my element:

```
$element['value']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxRefreshField'],
];
```

Next in my callback, how do I access the form_state value filled out in the field and the element defined on the form?

```
    public function ajaxRefreshField(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, Request $request) { 
      // What I want to do is something like this:
      $response = new AjaxResponse();
      $element = $form->get-my-element-in-some-sort-of-way
      $element['add-a-change'] = [...];
      $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('my-selector', $element));

      return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `$form_state->getValue('foo');`?

Comment: Yeah, but the form_state is a tree and it is possible my field is configured for example on a Paragraph... so I then I have to fetch the element from the paragraph definied on the form... I want to find a dynamic way to do this

Comment: Or if other contrib modules have ajax calls in their FieldWidget, I would be glad to check them, but I don't know of any...

Answer (score 1):

Grab the triggering element from the `$form_state` in your AJAX callback method:

```
$triggeringElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
$value = $triggeringElement['#value'];
```